# How to make installer pack of Java swing Application Project?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I've created a java project using swing application with JMF. I've tried to convert it into package but it failed.

The jar can be created but it won't work in other computer (Windows). Can someone know the answer? Please tell me.

I need to package the project as installer and it would work in other system. Guide me for this.

Comment: Include what error is showing. The two problems I think at are: 1) lack of other jars 2) lack of native liraries (if you are using multimedia)

Answer (score 3):

This link gives a list of opensource installers for java applications:

http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators

I'd recommend [izpack](http://izpack.org/), its used by a lot of software like jedit, scala installer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html). (Its not free though, you may try evaluation version first)

Answer (score 1):

Here is list of Open Source Installers Generators in Java :

http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators

I have used [Install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **install4j** for the create exe file for jar file of java project and use the **Inno Setup Compiler** file for create the installer for the project.
this ts Youtube vedio for the how to create the exe and installer

[video for create the exe and installer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSmhIunxVW4)