# create setup in java swing application

Tags: java, swing, jar, setup-project, setup-deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make installer pack of Java swing Application Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509562/how-to-make-installer-pack-of-java-swing-application-project)

I am working on java swing application in which  i have to give html files to the client to browse them in swing API.

Now i want to create the setup for the project so that user could install the software on their computer and i want to include html files , java classes some jar files and ms access database also how could i use the path of directory created after the installation of software.

Please suggest the code if possible

Comment: So you want an installer them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to install only on windows systems then try this:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Its simple to write scripts for the installer and it does everything a typical installer does.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to install (and automatically update) the app. itself.  JWS also offers the [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html) that will provide a hook to invoking the DB installer.  Here is a [demo. of the installer service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).