# Copying files from source to computer

Tags: java

I want to create an installer in java, that copy files from the source (like a packpage to put the files) to the Appdata folder, Is this possible? How can I make this?

Comment: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509562/how-to-make-installer-pack-of-java-swing-application-project

Comment: I will try this, tank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
String myAppFolderName = ".MyApp";
Path installDir = Paths.get(homeDir, "AppData");
if (!Files.isDirectory(installDir) { // Maybe not Windows
    installDir = Paths.get(homeDir);
}
Path myAppFolder = Paths.get(installDir.toString(), myAppFolderName);
Files.createDirectory(myAppFolder);

Path sources = Paths.get(new URI("jar:file://... .jar!/install_image"));
Files.copy(sources, myAppFolder);
```

For a jar's File, URI:

```
MyAppClass.class.getProtectionDomain()
    .getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
```

This uses

- A fall back whenever there is no AppData directory (as on Linux or Mac)
- Some subdirectory .MyApp to put everything in
- A zip file system ("jar:file:/...") for the unpacking
- A way to get the URI of a jar

You'll probably want to capture the case of running without jar too - for development.